# Fade in and out background images simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery, background-image

The problem is my background images are of different sizes and unpredictable, so using a CSS transition will animate the stretch, which looks ugly. Thus, I really need to do this with JS.

```
var images = [
    "http://ns223506.ovh.net/rozne/e800637ee8c7de5cdaed8df8ea3635f1/wallpaper-2585508.jpg",
    "http://ns223506.ovh.net/rozne/15382371cb0d5b9319f5f4469bbc4511/wallpaper-2585497.jpg"
];

var counter = 0;
setInterval(function () {
    $(".bg").css('backgroundImage', 'url("' + images[counter] + '")');

    $('<img>').attr('src', images[++counter]); // preload the next image

    if (counter == images.length) counter = 0;

}, 2000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mVAvF/1/

What I want to do is fade in the new background-image whilst fading out the old. Any suggestions?

Comment: `counter == images.length` should be `counter == (images.length-1)`, right? `images[2]` doesnt contain an element.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot fade one background into another in the same element.
You'll have to add another element on top of or behind the current background, then either fade the new element in if it is on top or fade the old one out if the new one is behind.

I answered a similar question before that contains a jsFiddle:
[jQuery background image rotation script - looking to modify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14500836/jquery-background-image-rotation-script-looking-to-modify/14501719#14501719)